# Uses of "this" Keyword

Tags: c#, this

I'm studying the uses of `this` and I think I understand it, at least partially, like when to solve ambiguity and to call methods from the "current" class, but one example from the book I'm reading(Head First C#) is giving me a hard time:

```
public void SpeakTo(Elephant whoToTalkTo, string message) {
    whoToTalkTo.TellMe(message, this);
}
```

In this method, is it safe to say that the `this` has the function of always refering to whatever object calls the method `SpeakTo()`, regardless of which class the call is written in?

Comment: `this` refers to the object itself. eg: `myFoo.speakTo(. . .)` would have `this` equal to `myFoo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In this method, is it safe to say that the "this" has the function of always refering to whatever object calls the method "SpeakTo()", regardless of which class the call is written in?

Nope. `this` does *not* refer to the object that calls `SpeakTo`. It refers to the object on which `SpeakTo` is called.

I will use some code to clarify this point

```
class Foo {
    public static void Main(String[] args) { 
        var foo = new Foo();
        foo.MyMethod();
    }

    public void MyMethod() {
         var bar = new Bar();
         bar.SpeakTo(anElephant, "Hello");
     }
}

class Bar {
    public void SpeakTo(Elephant whoToTalkTo, string message) {
       whoToTalkTo.TellMe(message, this);
    }
}
```

According to your statement, `this` refers to the `foo` variable that's created in the main method. This is *not* the case. `this` actually refers to `bar`. i.e. the object that's before the method name.

Comment: So, in other words, in "bar.SpeakTo()", "bar" is only a reference to where the method should be located and used( "bar" is not calling anything) and "this" serves the purpose of passing "bar" itself as an argument. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes @NeoTrader a `Foo` object called `foo` calls `SpeakTo()` _on_ `bar`.

Comment: Not always right.  If I write a class `BarChild` that inherits from `Bar`, then `this` is actually a pointer to an instance of `BarChild` not of `Bar`.  That is how polymorphism works.

Comment: @JohnWu "Not always right" which sentence do you mean? Most of the things I said here is in the OP's context, not general statements.

Comment: You're right Sweeper but I think you know what I'm getting at.  Just thought the answer would not be complete without pointing out that `this` is not always a reference to the currently executing type.

Answer (score 4):

No... Actually, `this` in your context refers to the object on which `SpeakTo` is defined, not the object which calls it.

Let's put it this way:

- Object `speaker` is of the class `Speaker` which defines the `SpeakTo`
  method,
- Object `caller` is calling the `speaker.SpeakTo()`, and
- Object `whoToTalkTo` is of the class which defines the `TellMe(string, Speaker)`

As you can see, `whoToTalkTo` is expecting the `Speaker` class instance. Then, the `speaker` object is precisely that, and it is free to pass `this` as the argument.

Now we can construct a larger example in which these relations are becoming more obvious:

```
class Speaker
{
    public int Data { get; set; }

    public void SpeakTo(Elephant whoToTalkTo, string message) 
    {
        // Passing current instance of this class as the argument
        whoToTalkTo.TellMe(message, this);
    }
}
```

This `Speaker` class contains a piece of state. Now I will use the `whoToTalkTo` object to change that state:

```
class Talker
{
    public void TellMe(string message, Speaker speaker)
    {
        speaker.Data = message.Length;
    }
}
```

This implementation is changing the state of one particular object which was passed to it.

Now the ultimate caller comes to the picture, the one which actually selects the `Speaker` object which will be subjected to the `TellMe()` method:

```
class Caller
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
        Talker talker = new Talker();

        Speaker one = new Speaker();
        Speaker two = new Speaker();

        // This sets one.Data to length of "something"
        one.SpeakTo(talker, "something");

        // This sets two.Data to length of "else"
        two.SpeakTo(talker, "else");

        Console.WriteLine(one.Data);
        Console.WriteLine(two.Data);
    }
}
```

This code will print values 9 and 4, which indicates that the `whoToTalkTo` has actually been modifying the state of two distinct objects.

Comment: The object "speaker" in your example is a reference variable from Class Speaker. What if I have more the one reference variable from class Speaker in the same class in which I'm wrinting this, for example, object "talker". If the "this" keyword refers simply to a Speaker class instance, regardless of what instance called SpeakTo(), how does the compiler know that it must pass "speaker" and not "talker" as the argument?

Comment: `this` keyword always refers to an object of the class in which it is written. `this` in the method of `Speaker` is the object of class `Speaker`; `this` in the method of `Talker` is the object of class `Talker`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the current object of the class which has method `SpeakTo`.

consider the following example:

```
public class A
{
      public void SpeakTo(Elephant whoToTalkTo, string message) {
          whoToTalkTo.TellMe(message, this);
       }
}
```

Now if you instantiate an object of `A` and calls the method `SpeakTo` it will be like:

```
A obj = new A();
obj.SpeakTo();
```

In the method `SpeakTo`, `this` refers to the current object, i.e. `obj`.

The signature of method `TellMe` should look like:

```
public void TellMe(string message, A objOfA)
```