# Using object as parameters in java

Tags: java, oop

```
class Test {

int a, b;

Test (int i,int j) 
{
    a=i;
    b=j;
    System.out.println("a is " + a);
}
boolean equalto(Test o)
{

if (o.a == a && o.b == b )
    return true;
else return false;

}
     }

class PassObj {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Test ob2 = new Test(100,22);
    Test ob3 = new Test(-1 ,-1);
    Test ob1 = new Test(100 ,22) ;

System.out.println(ob1.equalto(ob2));
System.out.println(ob1.equalto(ob3));



}
    }
```

In the above code may I know how  if condition is working.
say for 1st print statement in if statement ob2.a is compared with "a" i.e 100==a

my doubt is what is the value of "a" it is taking to compare and how ? I have tried to print that "a" value  before print statement is executed and I understood that when object is created and initiated those 3 values of "a" is getting printed as 100, -1 and 100.

Does ob1.equalto(ob2) calls constructor again ? if so then in my output shouldn't "a" get printed again. I am new to OOP and not clear with this concept.

My doubt is which "a" it will take when it is comparing for print statement 1 and 2 and how can I print only those 2 "a"

output I am getting now:

```
a is 100
a is -1
a is 100
true
false
```

Comment: The "a" in your object is a reference to the int value given to the constructor when you instantiated your object. The a of the other object is a reference to the int passed to the constructor when instantiating the second object. ob1.equalto(ob2) does not call the constructor again. Only using that constructor calls it.

Comment: It is comparing the a of the current object with the a from the object o that is passed. ob1.equalto(ob2)  will not call the constructor because ob1 and ob2 already exist and have been initialized. Once you have initialized an object it will not simply dissappear.

Comment: To have a more clear example about OOP, let's talk about a class called StackOverflowAccount with an attribute name : you created an account with the name CHIVID, and I got another with the name Jeremy Grand. When calling equalto between our two accounts, it will check your the name of your account (CHIVID) is the same as mine (Jeremy Grand).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know what specifically you're asking, but I'll try to explain some OOP concepts and hopefully you get it.

Here, you created three objects:

```
Test ob2 = new Test(100,22);
Test ob3 = new Test(-1 ,-1);
Test ob1 = new Test(100 ,22);
```

After the code is executed, the constructor is called three times. Therefore, three objects are created. `ob1`, `ob2`, `ob3` are like the labels you give them so that you can identify which is which later. Note that these three objects are completely independent. Every object here has an `a` and a `b` stored in it.

Now this line:

```
System.out.println(ob1.equalto(ob2));
```

Here you call `equalto` on `ob1` with an argument of `ob2`. Let's look at what happens inside the method. I think this part is where you're confused the most.

```
if (o.a == a && o.b == b )
    return true;
else return false;

}
```

Since you passed `ob2` as the parameter, `o` here basically means `ob2`. But what is the `a` on the right side of the `==`? This `a` is actually short for `this.a`. `this` means the object on which the method is called, in this case, `ob1`. If you want more info, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42259667/uses-of-this-keyword/42259873#42259873) out.

So you're comparing `ob1.a` and `ob2.a` here. The same thing happens with the next line.

Comment: @sweeper-  Instance variables inside method will have value of object on which method was invoked right !! In this case a and b. " it is actually short for this.a " so same thing applies to every  object parameter passing scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

Construtor gets called when you create an object like when you have written `Test ob2 = new Test(100,22);` at that time object gets created and Contructor gets called.

According to your requirement you have to print inside `equalto` method as follows:

```
boolean equalto(Test o)
{

    //if you use System.out.println(ob1.equalto(ob2)); then this.a will print ob1 'a' value 
    //and o.a will print ob2 'a' value
    System.out.println(this.a+"  "+o.a); //this.a 
    if (o.a == a && o.b == b )
        return true;
    else 
    return false;
}
```